# Spark shell and spark dataframe gives different results for parquet files

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have data in hdfs location /data/published/r6/omega which is full of parquet files ,
In that there is column etl_cre_tmst which has data . The parquet files has data

```
 val loc = "/data/published/r6/omega"
 val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(loc)
 df.select("etl_cre_tmst").show(10,false)

 +---------------------+
 |etl_cre_tmst         |
 +---------------------+
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 |2019-03-08 04:41:10.0|
 +---------------------+
```

But when i try to access the data via Hive table, it shows only null

```
 val df =  hc.sql("select etl_cre_tmst from db_r6.omega  ")
 df.show(10,false)

 +---------------------+
 |etl_cre_tmst         |
 +---------------------+
 |null|
 |null|
 |null|
 |null|
 |null|
 +---------------------
```

The parquet file schema and datatype for etl_cre_tmst  matches with hive table schema and datatype . the datatype for etl_cre_tmst  is timestamp in parquet files and in hive table also

Why am I get null values when I try to same data via spark-shell. when I access the same table via hive shell then it works. the issue is only with spark shell alone

can someone help?

Comment: May be datatype conversion issue . What is the data type?

Comment: datatype is timestamp in parquet files as well as in hive table ddl